# Mutual-exclusion using TestAndSet() instruction

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

The book Operating System Principles by Silberschatz, Galvin and Gagne contains the following definition for the TestAndSet() instruction in the chapter on synchronization:

```
boolean TestAndSet(boolean *target) {
    boolean rv = *target;
    *target = TRUE;
    return rv;
}
```

An implementation of mutual-exclusion using the above instruction is also provided as follows:

```
do {
    while(TestAndSetLock(&lock))
        ; // do nothing
        // critical section
    lock = FALSE;
        // remainder section
} while(TRUE);
```

Now, how is mutual exclusion achieved if there is no condition for setting *target* to TRUE?

Consider the following situation, process P0 sets the shared variable *lock* to TRUE and enters its critical section. Another process P1 calls TestAndSet() in the while loop above, it returns TRUE (since P0 has the lock) while unconditionally setting *lock* to FALSE. The second time TestAndSet() is called in the while loop it will return FALSE and P1 enters its critical section even though P0 is in its critical section. Mutual-exclusion is then violated.

I did some searching and stumbled upon a paper by Mithun Acharya and Robert Funderlic (of the North Carolina State University CS department) which contains the following alternative definition of TestAndSet():

```
   boolean Test-and-Set(boolean target)
    begin
        if(target == false):
            target = true;
        return target;
    end
```

This makes much more sense to me, I included it for comparison and also because the paper lists the book by Silberschatz as one of its references.

I just don't understand how the definition I found in my text book (the one I provided first) can be used to acheieve mutual exclusion, can anyone help?

Answer (score 19):

Here is a way to think about atomic TestAndSet intuitively.

A thread uses it before entering a critical region. Only two cases:

1. Lock is being held (*target is TRUE): return TRUE and *target remains TRUE
2. Lock is NOT being held: return FALSE, and *target is set to TRUE

So either another thread is in the critical region so *target (TRUE) reflects what the value should be; or "I" am entering this critical region now, so set *target to TRUE.

Comment: Could you also please explain why it doesn't satisfy bounded buffer condition??

Comment: @nj-ath, There is no definitive gurantee that a process that is waiting for lock gets the lock with certain fixed amount of time.

Comment: @nj-ath,

>If there are multiple processes trying to get into their critical sections, there is no guarantee of what order they will enter, and any one process could have the bad luck to wait forever until they got their turn in the critical section. (Since there is no guarantee as to the relative rates of the processes, a very fast process could theoretically release the lock, whip through their remainder section, and re-lock the lock before a slower process got a chance.)

Answer (score 6):

The implementation shown can be written more clearly like this:

```
while(TestAndSet(&lock))
{
   // spin in this loop until TestAndSet returns false
}
do_critical_section_stuff();
lock = FALSE;
// We've now left the critical section
```

I think the OP was misinterpreting it as:

```
while(TestAndSet(&lock))
{
   lock = FALSE;
}
do_critical_section_stuff();
```

which wouldn't work properly for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 6):

Ah I had that question also. Let me share my understanding.

Initially *target will be FALSE.(that's a given). 
It is true that P need to pass `while(TestAndSetLock(&lock)) ; // do nothing`
to obtain the lock and enter the **critical section**. (obtaining the lock is just an hypothetical thing, if it can pass the while loop then it has the lock)

*someone has the lock means **target** is **TRUE**, 
lock is free to be taken is **target** is **FALSE**.
so in the beginning it's like this,*

[image]

[image]

P1 (the very first to call the function will get lucky), he sees the target is FALSE and set it to true and RETURN FALSE, which leads it to avoid the while loop wait.

[image]

[image]

Now the target is TRUE.Other fact is **TestAndSet(boolean_ref lock)** *will return the called value*,
And **TestAndSet(boolean_ref lock)** will **ALWAYS** set the target to **TRUE**
so someone has to set target to FALSE in somewhere else (*so the one with the lock can set it to FALSE*)

Other P's will come and see that target is TRUE and when calling `TestAndSet(boolean_ref lock)` it will return TRUE always until P1 set target to false.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I found this nice graphical explanation from [This site, you can download it from here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~walpole/class/cse513/slides/3.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The TestAndSet function you initially quote is executed only when target is false. I.e. the thread is blocking until target is false. I don't have that text book, but I'm sure it's mentioned somewhere in the text.

Please note the TestAndSet is an "atomic" function that must be implemented in the lowest levels of the OS (or even by the instruction set of the CPU). If it's implemented in a user application, a context switch may occur between the test and the set, causing corruption.

Clarification: I'm only sure of the fact the function is executed when target is false because somewhere these must be a comparison operation that is blocking. There are two types of TestAndSet - one that returns only when the target is set to True (blocking), and one that may return False, i.e. return immediately (that one will enable polling by another thread). I assume the one you quote is blocking because it seems to return immediately after starting execution, which would mean the "IF" statement is executed by a lower level mechanism, e.g. the CPU or OS kernel.

Comment: I haven't come across the fact that TestAndSet() is executed only when target is false. I've checked both the textbook ad Wikipedia.

However, it does make sense, i'll look into it.

Comment: There's no blocking in the example shown, the `while(TestAndSet())` loop just spins until the condition changes.  While it's wasteful of CPU, threads don't actually *have* to block when waiting for something to happen.  Look up "spinlock" on Wikipedia for more context.

Answer (score 1):

To use the testAndset method, we begin with a variable called Lock, which is set to false:

```
HdwareData lock = new HdwareData(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the implementation of the mutual exclusion of TestAndSet(&lock), one can safely say that as long as TestAndSet returns true, the process(P) will not enter its critical section. The process will continue executing in its loop condition until it(the condition) fails.  
  
 The condition will succeed(TestAndSet will return true) as long as another process has a lock on the resource. When another process has a lock on the resource, the value of lock is true. As soon as the other process releases its hold over the resource, by setting lock = false, TestAndSet will return false.  
  
When TestAndSet returns false, the condition for the while loop fails and hence process P enters its critical section.
  
  
TestAndSet is an atomic operation, ie it is executed without interruptions. This is done to prevent race conditions with the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Think non-linearly. You pointed out three issues in the definition Silberchatz provided to implement the *testAndSet()* function:

(1) you correctly stated that *target* is set to TRUE unconditionally, and realized (mistakenly) that is a problem.

(2) In order to address the problem in (1) (which is non-existent), you proposed that *target* be tested before setting it to TRUE.

(3) Finally, you showed your concerns regarding the fact that *result* is set to FALSE also unconditionally by the block that implements the Mutual Exclusion (this does not actually happen).

I will  try to clarify these issues. Initially, note that the first thing the function *TestAndSet()* does is to copy the value of *target* to *rv* and only afterwards *target* is set unconditionally to TRUE. Now, the catch: if *target* was originally FALSE, *TestAndSet()* sets *target* to TRUE and returns FALSE, so the process can enter the critical section. In case the original *target* value was TRUE, it is set to TRUE anyway (which causes no harm) and *TestAndSet()* returns TRUE, so the process can NOT enter the critical region. So, setting *target* unconditionally to TRUE is not a problem and issue (1) proves non-existent.

Regarding issue (2), once it is demonstrated above that it is harmless to set *target* to TRUE unconditionally, there is no need to test its value beforehand.

Issue (3) is also non-existent because *result* is not really set unconditionally to FALSE. I mean, it is, but only AFTERWARDS the critical region has been processed by the process; i.e., when the mutual exclusion is no longer necessary. The process HAS TO set *target* to FALSE as soon as it leaves the critical section (it is not supposed to block any other processes after exiting the critical section). It is mandatory to release the lock after processing the critical section!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following highlighted part in your question:

> Consider the following situation, process P0 sets the shared variable lock to TRUE and enters its critical section. Another process P1 calls TestAndSet() in the while loop above, it returns TRUE (since P0 has the lock) ***while unconditionally setting lock to FALSE***. The second time TestAndSet() is called in the while loop it will return FALSE and P1 enters its critical section even though P0 is in its critical section. Mutual-exclusion is then violated.

The P1(or any process), irrespective of lock being True or False, doesn't set the value of lock to False.

- If the lock is value is False, it enters critical section and sets its value to True, thereby grabbing the lock.
- If the lock value is True, it does nothing(sets its value to True, thereby not changing it) and waits for the lock value to turn to False(which happens when process that has the lock completes the execution of its critical section).